# It is proper to make mt19937 static in a class

Tags: c++11, random, random-seed, mt19937

Let's say I have a class as below:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test() : mt((std::random_device())()), dist1(0, 10), dist2(0, 100) {}
    void func() {
        if (dist1(mt) < 4) {
            // do something
        }
    }
    void func2() {
        if (dist2(mt) > 25) {
            // do something
        }
    }
private:
    std::mt19937 mt;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist1;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist2;
};
```

As you see, there are two functions, they all need a random number to do something.

In this case, can I make the data member `std::mt19937 mt` as static and initialize it in cpp file?

```
class Test {
...
private:
    static std::mt19937 mt;
...
};
// cpp file
std::mt19937 Test::mt((std::random_device())());
```

I just tried and it seemed to work. But I don't know if there is something wrong with it.

```
Test t1; t1.func(); t1.func2();
Test t2; t2.func(); t2.func2();
```

Can I say that static or non-static won't cause any difference for the piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I say that static or non-static won't cause any difference for the piece of code?

If you care about the specific sequence of numbers that each instance of `Test` will observe, yes. However you are seeding these with `std::random_device`, so I suspect you don't care about that.

If you have calls to these methods on multiple threads, the static version has a data race. I would use `thread_local`, not `static`, to share `std::mt19937`s.

Comment: `the specific sequence of numbers`: do you mean that `static mt19937` may produce the same sequence number for `t1.func()` and `t2.func()`?

Comment: @Yves no, `t1.func(); t1.func();` would be the same as `t1.func(); t2.func();` etc (assuming the seed was the same)

Comment: Alright, I think I would make `mt19937` non static but make the two `std::uniform_int_distribution` static...